# Plot multiple frames of different size on the same window

Tags: r, graphics, graph, plot

Consider this example:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
frame()
image(matrix(1:100, nrow=100), main="my wide plot", axes=FALSE)
frame()
plot(rnorm(120), rnorm(120), main="plot 1")
plot(dpois(0:20, lambda=6), type="b", main="plot 2")
x = rnorm(100)
y = x+runif(100, 10, 12)
plot(x=x, y=y, , main="plot 3")
```

[image]

How can I do to make my first graph (`image(...)` titled `my wide plot`) to occupy the 3 frames on top of the window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way would be to use `layout()`:

```
layout(mat=matrix(c(1,1,1,2,3,4), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE))

image(matrix(1:100, nrow=100), main="my wide plot", axes=FALSE)    
plot(rnorm(120), rnorm(120), main="plot 1")
plot(dpois(0:20, lambda=6), type="b", , main="plot 2")
x = rnorm(100)
y = x+runif(100, 10, 12)
plot(x=x, y=y, main="plot 3")
```

[image]

(For a nice example of a much more sophisticated layout, [see here](http://menugget.blogspot.com/2013/01/my-template-for-controlling-publication.html).)